# How to check which Jenkins plugin/service constantly making calls to GitHub API?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, github-api

Our jenkins server (version 2.164.2) keeps making lot of requests to Github so it exceeds the Github API rate limit. Github support team found out that a user-agent string `git-credential-manager` contributed to 60% of the Api calls. Most of the calls are https://api.github.com/user/subscriptions and the agent is
`git-credential-manager (Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0; Win32NT; x64) CLR/4.0.30319 git-tools/1.20.0   597,376 57.032%`

From process explorer, it shows that Jenkins trigger lot of git-credential-manager:
[image]

We added some Log Recorders in Jenkins for `org.jenkinsci.plugins.github` and `org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source` but they don't make lot of github calls. Is there anyway to figure out which Jenkins plugins are making those calls?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to figure out which Jenkins plugins are making those calls?

I'm not familiar enough with Jenkins to comment on this, but I can tell you a bit more about the behaviour you're seeing as that might help you identify the root cause.

`git.exe` is invoking `git-remote-https.exe` to interact with GitHub over HTTPS, which then invokes `git-credential-manager` as that's the configured helper script to obtain credentials. `git-credential-manager` is then invoking `api.github.com/v3/user/subscriptions` to test if the credential it has (likely stored in the Windows Credential Store) is valid.

https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/blob/1145b59498378a7ddbccdc45b216e17ef0d0a664/GitHub.Authentication/Src/Authority.cs#L190-L208

I don't believe this is tied to a specific plugin, but more to Jenkins working with private repositories and invoking Git on the machine. If you are working with private GitHub repositories, this could be consuming API calls for the account that is authenticating which results in it being rate-limited.

I'd check for these sorts of operations in your build process:

- build setups that don't cache the repository on disk between builds (if that's supported)
- builds that that include fetch/push/pull steps (more builds, more API calls)
- cloning repositories or submodules on-the-fly in scripts

Comment: Thanks Brendan. We use GitHub Branch Source and jenkinsfile to build. We have custom scripts but it has nothing to do with pull/fetch from Github. so we will need to investigate further.